# Catching the exeception after issuing the Import command on Apache Solr From Java

Tags: java, solr, solrj

In of our high priority project we have implemented Solr Elastic Search which import's the data from Source System and based on the import we will be doing further validation to populate the data in other system.

But here is the problem which we are facing.

How to catch exception/errors which occured during data import. I see in SOLR logs the connection to source could not be established and complete stack trace of the exception. But how can i catch this programatically ??

i.e. 
QueryResponse response = dataCore.query("URL for full import on the CORE");

The response did not contain any of the error information. Is there a way to capture this and process further only if data import is successfull.

Any help will be much appericiated.

Comment: _Solr_ and _ElasticSearch_ are two different products.

Answer (score 0):

I see no easy way. If the error message in the response is not sufficient, then you can either

- write code to monitor the solr log files
- change the solr logger config to send the errors to your application (email appender for example)